# Bootstrap colorpicker not updating value on change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a form using bootstrap, one of the inputs is a colorpicker element.
When users pick a color, the value attribute remains the same.
It seems that value attribute remains to whatever it was initially.

I am using: `bootstrap@v5.3.2` and `jquery@v3.7.1`

Here is my color input:

```html
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <label class="col col-form-label" for="priceColor">Price Color</label>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="color" class="form-control form-control-color" id="priceColor" value="#563d7c" title="Choose your color"> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my javacript:

```js
$('#priceColor').on('change', function() {
  console.log($('#priceColor').attr('value'))
});
```

The code above does get triggered when the color is changed, however the value remains the same as stated above.

Just to be clear, I am not using [bootstrap-colorpicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-colorpicker).
I am only using Bootstrap's [colorpicker](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#color).

I don't know where/if the value is stored elsewhere but it does not get stored on the html element.

Comment: When you want to get the updated value, shouldnt we use `$(this).val()` ??
This will give a detail explanation 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835859/jquery-1-7-1-text-inputs-value-not-updating-in-firebug-inspect-element-but/10836011#10836011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the current color value, instead you are printing the initial fixed value that you have specified in the html.

```
$("#priceColor").on("change", function () {
      console.log($(this).val());
});
```

This will provide the current color code.